# Action hook on Edit custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, actions, metabox

Is there an explicit action hook that will fire when (or just before) the admin Edit page renders for a custom post type? Something similar to {$new_status}_{$post->post_type}?

I'm trying to find the least obtrusive place to insert my add_meta_box() registration so that it's not calling that function on every page refresh, but only when it's needed (ie: the user wants to create a new custom post or edit an existing custom post).

Thanks for your thoughts / code snippets!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`register_post_type()` has a registration option called `'register_meta_box_cb'`. Set that to a valid callback and it will call that function only when it is compiling the meta boxes for that post type's edit screen. Something like this:

```
register_post_type( 'foo', array(
  'public' => true,
  'label' => 'foo',
  'register_meta_box_cb' => 'bar',
));

function bar(){
  add_meta_box('blah', 'blah', /* etc */ );
}
```

Comment: Bloody outstanding! I missed that one. Your answer fits my requirements exactly! But, going back to my original question, IS there some way to hook into when the Edit page is invoked? I even tried edit_post and that didn't seem to fire under any circumstance (even for posts!)

Comment: Try 'admin_head-edit.php' if you want your code to fire on the edit.php page itself. 'save_post' and 'edit_post' fire on saving changes (including auto-drafts) to a post.

Comment: The method John posted is the proper way of adding metaboxes to a particular post type, beyond that method the alternative is to register metaboxes on the `add_meta_boxes` or  `add_meta_boxes-$type`  action(those actions exist specifically for metabox registration).